# "Neither Michael nor Albert is correct" or "Neither Michael nor Albert are correct"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers, neither-nor, disjunction

What is the correct sentence?

> Neither Michael nor Albert is correct.

> Neither Michael nor Albert are correct.

Comment: Neither are is not correct. :D

Comment: IMHO *neither are* **incorrect**, but I admit it sounds a bit odd to say that *neither is* **always** *correct* in the same sentence!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*Neither Michael nor Albert **is** correct* — this is the correct version per prescriptive  rules.

Based on my understanding of grammar lessons,

- When connecting singular nouns, use a singular verb:

  > *Neither Jacob nor Jane **is** coming to the party.*
- When connecting plural nouns, use a plural verb:

  > *Neither the Jones nor the Smiths **are** coming to the party.*
- When combining singular and plural nouns, the agreement is decided by the noun that is closer to the verb:

  > - *Neither the boys nor Susan **is** coming to the party.*
  >   ⇑ Verb determined by *Susan*.
  > - *Neither Susan nor the boys **are** coming.*
  >   ⇑ Verb determined by *the boys*.

  (Some books say it's better to put the plural noun closer to the verb and use the plural form of the verb.)

References:

- [Capital Community College Guide to Grammar & Writing: Subject-Verb Agreement](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm)
- [esl.about.com English Tip of the Day: 170 Neither ... nor](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarintermediate/p/tip170.htm)

Comment: I think the term is a "partitive conjunction" - ie it joins the two words together, but it analyses as being the separate parts for verb agreement - it's like "each" in that sense.

Comment: I've read a number of threads on this confusing topic, but am I correct to think that the same rules would apply to "either"?

Answer (score 11):

I disagree with existing answers confidently claiming that **Neither X nor Y** is always singular. Assume for the sake of argument that you (reading this) are "you"...

**Neither you nor I is** [likely to use the singular](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither%20you%20nor%20I%20is,neither%20you%20nor%20I%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in this (self-referential) construction...

[image]

...which for my money suggests that around 1850 some pedantic grammarians started proposing that the singular should always be used, but the native speakers of English still aren't listening.

---

Here's another example from Google Books where the supposedly ungrammatical version dwarfs "correct" usage. Grammar *is* the codified description of what people actually say; it makes no sense to claim that what the overwhelming majority of native speakers prefer is "wrong".

> *neither he nor I **are*** [(About 2,500 results)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22zinc%20the%20metal%20effervesces%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22neither%20he%20nor%20I%20are%22&tbm=bks)
>    *neither he nor I **am*** [(About 13,400 results)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22neither%20he%20nor%20I%20am%22)
>    *neither he nor I **is*** [(About 743 results)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22zinc%20the%20metal%20effervesces%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22neither%20he%20nor%20I%20is%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: Pam Peters agrees, as you may have seen from my answer to Fran's question 'Neither is or neither are' earlier today.

Comment: @Barrie: It's not at all clear to me what Peters means there by saying *The singular verb seems to particularize while the plural one generalizes*, so perhaps you can enlighten me. I was prompted to post this answer because having remembered this earlier question, and flagged the other as a dup, it just dawned on me that there's a real issue involved here. I have no special opinion of what's "correct", or whether "it depends on context", but the answers here do seem to fly in the face of accepted usage for some constructions.

Comment: Pam Peters’s comments are as much words on the page to me as they are to you, but ‘Neither director nor producer has much experience’ might be rewritten as ‘The director doesn’t have much experience and nor does the producer.’ That particularizes. ‘Neither director nor producer have much experience’ might be rewritten as ‘The director and the producer don’t have much experience’. That generalizes.

Comment: Well I applaud your efforts there, but I'm afraid neither you nor Pam has/have managed to drum any understanding of the difference into me! :)

Comment: At least there can be no disputing her claim that '. . . research for the "Longman Grammar" (1999) shows that the use of the plural verb is quite common.'

Comment: I'm certainly not going to dispute the claim, even though I can't access either her text or the research. But I do find the "sudden" appearance of the singular in my NGram to be somewhat suspicious. It really does look like what Steven Pinker is pleased to call [the language mavens](http://mavensays.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Question: going by the use of syllepsis in "neither... nor" constructions, where the verb agrees with the quanity after "nor", should this be "Neither you nor I AM"?

Comment: @Kaiser Octavius: I guess it would have to be if you believe the (to my mind, ridiculous) assertion by Manjima *agreement is decided by the noun that is closer to the verb*. Noting the number of upvotes for that answer, and the fact that someone has just *downvoted* mine, I have to wonder if I speak the same language as many of the folk here. Maybe it's just that there are a lot of non-native speakers, plus plenty more who prefer style guides over actual usage.

Comment: Darn, my upvote to Majima is already locked. It took me too long to read the comments.

Comment: @CopperKettle: It's interesting that almost everyone posting/voting on [the  related ELL question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/) agrees that the idea ***neither/none** are always singular* is on a par with not splitting infinitives or ending sentences with prepositions (i.e. - these "rules" exist mainly in the minds of pedants, all but ignored by native speakers speaking "naturally"). But relatively speaking I'm a voice in the wilderness here on ELU (which one *might* have expected to cater more for users who know *real* English, not just "how to pass an English exam").

Comment: Using your links, I get  **616 results** for "neither he nor I is". The "…nor am I" more or less tallies, but for "…nor I are" it's  only [**2,190** hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neither+he+nor+I+are%22&tbm=bks&ei=HSlJWtuQE8jP6ATBnKqwDQ&start=70&sa=N&biw=1302&bih=620&dpr=1.1).

Comment: You need to update the two old Google links, the results are very different six years later.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Duly updated. But it's thrown up something *neither my cat nor I **are** able to understand*. We accept the possibility that my *neither you nor I **is/are*** chart might be misleading because ***you are*** is valid, but ***you is*** isn't. But I see that if I include *neither you nor I **am*** in the chart, it's even less common than *...nor I **is***. And comparing ***are/is/am*** instances in those *neither **you** nor I* charts with the same startting with *neither **he** nor I* gives the same relative prevalence for both. It's all a bit confusing, given the ***Books*** hits.

Answer (score 8):

This is correct:

> Neither Michael nor Albert is correct.

Singular subjects joined with *or* or *nor* take singular verb agreement, so you also say:

> Either Michael or Albert is incorrect.

Comment: *Singular* subjects so joined do. Cf: "Neither the Jones nor the Smiths are correct."

Comment: Good point -- and it gets sticky when one is plural and one is singular.  "Neither the Smiths nor Michael are/is correct."  No idea on the prescriptive rule, but I think people often go for whichever one is closest to the verb (often without thinking about it).

Comment: Although "Neither M nor A is correct" doesn't mean the same as "Either M or A is incorrect". In the first phrase both people are wrong, the second phrase means that one of them is wrong and the other is right.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version sounds like it's the answer to a question like, "Which is your real name? Albert, or Michael?"

The second sounds normal to a native speaker :o)

Answer (score -2):

Rephrase it:

> Not one of them is correct.

as opposed to:

> Not one of them are correct.

QED :)

Comment: -1 As it avoids the problem, but only by avoiding the question.

Comment: @vanden, I think what Skilldrick means is to rephrase it as an exercise, and then choose "Neither Michael nor Albert is correct" on that basis.

Comment: @Tony, yes, that was what I was going for, thanks.

Comment: That kind of "proof" just doesn't work in linguistics.

Comment: In addition to what the others have mentioned, this sentence is not interchangeable with the exemplified one: You are assuming that the antecedents of the pronoun are known without enough context to make that determination. Even if I posit the likelihood of both of these names being mentioned, what if the purpose of this sentence is to remove two invalid options a list of three or more, where one of the options is correct? It would not work in that case, because you would be suggesting that *all* of the options are incorrect.