# "Neither is" or "neither are"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Which is correct, “neither is” or “neither are”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are)

Which is correct?

> No, neither of these websites **is** biased as they give a wide range of informative information without being one sided.
>
> No, neither of these websites **are** biased as they give a wide range of informative information without being one sided.

I am confused about the subject-verb agreement here.

Answer (score 7):

*Neither* is the subject (it is being used as a pronoun).  It is generally singular, as evidenced in the sample usage at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/neither).  So you should go with

> No, neither of these websites is biased, as they both give a wide range of good information without being one-sided.

Note, however, as recorded in [another EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/neither-michael-nor-albert-is-correct-or-neither-michael-nor-albert-are-correct), that the pluralization depends on which two entities are being compared.  In this case you are comparing one website with another website, so the singular is clearly called for; but if you were comparing one group of things with another group, the plural could be used:

> Neither the Smiths nor the Wessons are available for dinner.

Answer (score 5):

As so often, [‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052162181X), based as it is on corpus data, challenges the traditional view:

> . . . research for the ‘Longman Grammar’ (1999) shows that the use of
> the plural verb is quite common. In fact singular and plural agreement
> have slightly different effects. Compare:
>
> *Neither director nor producer has much experience.*
>
> *Neither director nor producer have much experience.*
>
> The singular verb seems to particularize while the plural one
> generalizes. The use of a plural verb there is as natural as it would
> be in a matching positive statement: *Both director and producer have
> plenty of experience.*

Answer (score 1):

In *"English Grammar in Use (Intermediate, unit 88)"*, it is said that After Neither of .... a singular or plural verb is possible:

> - Neither of the children wants (or want) to go to bed.
>
> Note: Neither restaurant & Neither of the restaurants
>
> - Neither restaurant is expensive.
> - Neither of the restaurants we went was (or were) expensive.

Comment: Plural may be accepted in informal or vernacular English, but it is not correct grammar.