# In which form should verbs following nominal phrases like "none of you", "either of you", etc. be?

Tags: verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [None as plural indefinite pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun)
>   [“Are either of you free?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8150/are-either-of-you-free)

Which of these is correct: "neither of you **are**" or "neither of you **is**"? "Which (one) of you **are**" or "which (one) of you **is**"? I think it should be "is" in both cases, since "neither of you" is not a second-person reference, and therefore should not take a second-person verb.

Answer (score 0):

'is' denotes singular, 'are' plural

So "Which one of you is .." is the correct from.

But, "Neither of you are .." is ONLY the more correct form.  I could say "Neither of you are my first choice." or "Neither of you is the one I would choose."; both being correct form.

Answer (score 0):

The question of whether you should use **neither is** or **neither are** has been answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47999/neither-is-or-neither-are) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are).

As for the correct verb form after **which** in a question, it depends. If you want to refer to a singular person, you should ask "Which of you is...?" But if you want to refer to more than one person, then the plural form is acceptable, as in *"Which of you are ready to follow me?"* Note, however, that this form sounds a bit stilted; a more natural way to ask this question would be *"Who is ready to follow me?"*

Comment: I see. But I've read elsewhere that when asking a question you would say, "ARE either of you..." even for the second-person. Why's that? "IS either of you..." does sound a little strange, in my opinion.

Comment: @KaiserOctavius: Both forms are acceptable. *"Are either of you..."* is more common in informal speech, perhaps that's why it sounds more natural.